# Generating Entity Keys

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4

I have run into my first dissapointment with Entity Framework 4. It turns out that SQL CE, when used with EF4, [does not support autogenerated primary keys](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/48984bd4-0921-4637-bd8f-8aa1ae9514ab/). I get a System.Data.UpdateException from OnjectContext.SaveChanges() with this message:

*Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported by SQL Server Compact.*

So, now I have to manually generate keys for my entities. Assuming I want to use auto-incremented integer keys, what is the best way to go about generating and keeping track of the keys when using Entity Framework? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the link in your question is a suggested solution. See [SQL Compact, Identity Columns and Entity Framework](http://sibagy.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D96C7B6CE19A2F61!1152.entry) perhaps you might want to implement an extension method like the one outlined.

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately, the code on the linked page only works for unfiltered entity sets, since the extension method returns the max id in the entity set. So, I ended up using a GUID as the entity key. I created a partial class for each entity with this constructor code: this.ID = Guid.NewGuid()

Answer (score 0):

I don't think David's idea is a good idea, however, I have no choice.
Maybe CE will support autogenerated primary keys in next version.

Comment: Actually, SQL Compact does support autogenerated keys--apparently, it's EF4 that doesn't support autogenerated keys from SQL Compact. The blog post linked in my original question explains the problem.