# GUID or int entity key with SQL Compact/EF4?

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4

This is a follow-up to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480084/generating-entity-keys) I posted on EF4 entity keys with SQL Compact. SQL Compact doesn't allow server-generated identity keys, so I am left with creating my own keys as objects are added to the `ObjectContext`. My first choice would be an integer key, and the previous answer linked to a [blog post](http://sibagy.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D96C7B6CE19A2F61!1152.entry) that shows an extension method that uses the `Max` operator with a selector expression to find the next available key:

```
public static TResult NextId<TSource, TResult>(this ObjectSet<TSource> table,  Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector) 
    where TSource : class
{
    TResult lastId = table.Any() ? table.Max(selector) : default(TResult);

    if (lastId is int)
    {
        lastId = (TResult)(object)(((int)(object)lastId) + 1);
    }

    return lastId;
}
```

Here's my take on the extension method: It will work fine if the `ObjectContext` that I am working with has an unfiltered entity set. In that case, the `ObjectContext` will contain all rows from the data table, and I will get an accurate result. But if the entity set is the result of a query filter, the method will return the last entity key in the filtered entity set, which will not necessarily be the last key in the data table. So I think the extension method won't really work.

At this point, the obvious solution seems to be to simply use a GUID as the entity key. That way, I only need to call `Guid.NewGuid()` method to set the ID property before I add a new entity to my `ObjectContext`.

Here is my question: Is there a simple way of getting the last primary key in the data store from EF4 (without having to create a second `ObjectContext` for that purpose)? Any other reason not to take the easy way out and simply use a GUID? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The approach you show does not look thread safe at all!  What's to stop two threads from getting the same ID?

Comment: Not an issue for me--I only use SQL CE for single-user applications, and I only generate records on a single thread. Good point though, if someone wants to multi-thread record creation in SQL CE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with a GUID.

- The size/performance issues aren't
  critical (or even noticeable) with SQL Compact, since
  it is a local, single-user system.
  It's not like the app will be
  managing an airline reservation
  system.
- And at least at this point, there
  seems to be no way around the "no
  server-generated keys" limitation of
  the SQL Compact/EF4 stack. If someone has a clever hack, I'm still open to it.

That doesn't mean I would take the same approach in SQL Server or SQL Express. I still have a definite preference for integer keys, and SQL Compact's bigger siblings allow them in conjunction with EF4.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Guid.  AutoIncrement is not supported on Compact Framework with Entity Framework.

Also, if you ever want to create a application which uses multiple data sources, int PK's are going to fall apart on you very, very quickly.

- With Guid's, you can juse call Guid.NewGuid() to get a new key.
- With int's, you have to hit the database to get a valid key.

If you store data in multiple databases, int PK's will cause conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done for SQL CE before, and I assume we have a single application accessing the database, is to calculate the MAX value on startup and put it in a static variable.  You can now hand out sequential values easily and you can make the code to generate them thread safe very easily.

Comment: I actually considered that approach, and it's a good one. I ended up going with GUID because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

One reason to avoid Guids would be size = memory and storage space consumption.

You could also query SQL Compact metadata like so:

SELECT AUTOINC_NEXT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Categories' AND AUTOINC_NEXT IS NOT NULL

Comment: How would I execute that query using EF4?